# investigations on Pollard's rho algorithm

Tags: factoring

I haven't understood Pollard's rho.  I decided to do away with the polynomial requirement and see what happens.  I started with $N = 33.$  I selected at random the numbers $7, 8, 1, 3, 26, 31 \mod\ 33$ as my $x$ sequence.  I kept track of the $y$ sequence $\mod 3$ which was $1, 2, 1, ...$  Bingo: we found a collision with $y_1$ and $y_3.$  Let's see if we have $|x_1 - x_3|$ revealing a factor of $33$: $|7 - 1| = 6$ and $\gcd(6, 33) = 3.$

Maybe that was just luck.  The fact I chose $3$ as a factor gives me too great of a chance perhaps.

I then picked $13\times19 = 247.$  The random numbers of the $x$ sequence were $57, 128, 231, 24 ...$ The $y$ sequence $\mod\ 13$ was $5, 11, 10, 11 ...$ Found a collision at $y_2, y_4.$  Does $|x_2 - x_4|$ reveal a factor?  $|128 - 24| = 104$ and $\gcd(104, 247) = 13.$

Still lucky perhaps.

I then took $N = 57\times257.$  The $x$ sequence was $$10848, 9291, 9501, 4055, 12300, 13061, 12492, 13860.$$  The $y$ sequence, which is $x \mod\ 57$ is $$18, 0, 39, 8, 45, 8, 9, 9, ...$$

We have a collision between $y_4$ and $y_6.$  Does $|x_4 - x_6| = |4055 - 13061| = 9006$ reveal a factor? $\gcd(9006, 14649) = 57.$

Is this still luck?

The polynomial must make a difference and I'm totally ignoring it and still finding factors.  Can you guide me into some light here?  Thank you.

Comment: Try the eighth Fermat number.  1238926361552897 * 93461639715357977769163558199606896584051237541638188580280321.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_rho_algorithm) is pretty good at explaining that the function of the polynomial is to be a pseudorandom source of $x_n$s.  Since collision relies on the [birthday paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_paradox), any other suitable random sequence should serve.  The advantage of polynomials is that we can regenerate the same sequence anywhere we like.  The Floyd and Brent cycle-finding algorithms allow us to find cycles in the values of the polynomials $\mod N$ keeping track of only two $x_i$ at a time.  Finding collisions by your method requires keeping vastly more $x_i$ ($O(\sqrt{N})$, in general).

Note that the runtime of Pollard's rho is frequently listed as $\sqrt{N}$, but that is because one does not know a priori $p$, the least prime factor of $N$, so writing the more accurate runtime, $\sqrt{p}$ is noninformative.  Your experiments also utilize information about $p$, so do not represent the situation for general factoring.  Reducing modulo $N$ would more accurately capture the situation in general factoring, and this can mask collisions modulo $p$.  (For instance, $2$ and $5$ are collisions modulo $3$, but not modulo $33$.)

For $N = 33$, $p = 3$ and $\sqrt{p} = 1.7\dots$.  We expect a collision in a multiple of $2$ tries.

For $N = 247$, $p = 13$ and $\sqrt{p} = 3.6\dots$.  We expect a collision in a multiple of $4$ tries.

For $N = 14649$, $p = 57$ and $\sqrt{57} = 7.5\dots$.  We expect a collision in a multiple of $8$ tries.

I write "in a multiple of" because being $O(\sqrt{p})$ only means that we know the shape of growth.  A constant multiple of $\sqrt{p}$ is also $O(\sqrt{p})$.  The multiple could be anything, bigger than $1$, less than $1$, we don't know without vastly more understanding of the relevant number theory.  Also, all of these examples are "tiny".  The "big-O" notation really only describes the asymptotic (very large) behaviour of the function.  For these miniscule examples, the behavioue could be very far away from the asymptotic behaviour.

Comment: I think I see it.  With a true random sequence, we couldn't have the cycle repeating itself after a first collision, so we would have to memorize the entire sequence (being unable to use Floyd's algorithm), losing the constant-space-achievement.  The polynomials give us the repeatable sequence and that's why we use it.  I think that explains your comment for me to try the 8th Fermat number.  I would have to keep in memory a long list and would surely fail to do so.  Using a polynomial and applying Floyd's algorithm, I would have to keep just two values of the sequence.

Comment: By the way, seeing answers you've given to other posts shows what a true think you are.  Thanks for taking the time to consider the question.  Very appreciated.

Comment: @T.Ingram : Glad to help!

Comment: Eric Towers, a [new question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2570664) came up, in case you have the time.