# Pollard's rho without directly checking for collisions

Tags: factoring

This is after this [other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2569932) answered.  In the previous question, I understood that to look for a collision without Floyd's algorithm would be space costly.  Now I have this new question.

Suppose we have a collision mod $p$ given two random numbers.  Then AFAIK we're guaranteed to have found a factor of $N$, whether it's $N$ itself or some non-trivial factor.  This will be discovered by the gcd computation.  So why should I look for collisions directly in the sequence mod $N$?  Won't the gcd tell me so?

To look at the question a little closer, I wrote the following program.  It uses the random number generator from Python and checks whether the algorithm has had a certain amount of chance.  If it goes beyond that limit, we stop with failure.   (I chose the limit $2 \sqrt{N}$.)

```
def rho_random(N):
  chances = 0
  def random_mod_N(): 
    i = random.randint(1, N - 1)
    return i
  while True:
    if 2*int(sqrt(N)) <= chances:
      return "unlucky"
    a = random_mod_N()
    b = random_mod_N()
    d = gcd(a - b, N)
    chances = chances + 1
    if d == N:
      return "trivial factor"
    if 1 < d and d < N:
      return d
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Greatest common divisor computations are expensive in time, compared to not doing them.  The [variant of Pollard and Brent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_rho_algorithm#Variants) takes, for example, $100$ candidates, multiplies them together, then computes the $\gcd$.  This replaces $100$ $\gcd$s with $99$ multiplies and $1$ $\gcd$.  Multiplies (modulo $N$) are vastly faster than $\gcd$s ($O(\log n)$ faster from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor#Complexity)).

Pollard and Brent describe and analyze this variant in Brent, Richard P. (1980), "An Improved Monte Carlo Factorization Algorithm", BIT 20: 176–184, [doi:10.1007/BF01933190](https://maths-people.anu.edu.au/~brent/pd/rpb051i.pdf).  This idea is described in section 5 of the cited paper.  In section 7, they discuss not even multiplying in $|x_i-x_j|$ with $i$ and $j$ too close.  With this modification, their runtimes reduce by about 24%.

(As regards [your prior question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2569932/investigations-on-pollards-rho-algorithm/2569967?noredirect=1#comment5305357_2569967), they have an analysis in section 8 of empirical data for the sufficiently random-ness of iterated polynomials for this method.)

Comment: I'm a little lost.  Is the polynomial really required or is it the case that any random source will do?  After reading section 5 of the cited paper, I had the impression that `rho_random` would be the variation discussed in section 5.  Brent says we can replace the `done := (x = y)` with `done := gcd(...)` which I think is what `rho_random` does.  But Brent still uses a polynomial and `rho_random` doesn't.

Comment: @T.Ingram : They first talk about using iteration of a polynomial to produce a sequence   of values.  Then at "It is plausible to assume that $f \,(\mod{p})$ behaves like a 'random' function and ...", they switch to assuming that your sequence of $x_n$ is "random".  Then they talk about avoiding too many $\gcd$ calculations by batching them up.  Your `rho_random` does use the $\gcd$ termination condition, but does more $\gcd$s than is likely optimal.

Comment: Okay.  That's understood.  It does more gcds than another procedure which batches them up.  But check this out.  I have two procedures whose only difference AFAIK is the source of randomness.  They both compute a factor, but the one with the polynomial is **much** faster than the one with Python's `random` as source of randomness.  See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2571676).